# Pull data from sql to salesforce

Tags: reporting, data-loader, sql, sqlserver

I am looking to generate reports and dashboards on Salesforce and the data reside in my SQL server.
How do pull data from SQL to Salesforce in order to create reports & dashboards in salesforce

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the SQL data external and use Salesforce Connect (paid add-on product) to view the data in Salesforce.

Or you could add Einstein Analytics or Tableau to reach out and report on the data.  This option is nice, since the dashboard visualizations are a lot richer.  But more work to set up.

The above options assume you have the budget and that the SQL database is externally connectable.

If the amount of data isn't huge, you could set up a custom process to reach out and import all the data into Salesforce each night.  Use Apex if the SQL data has a REST API, or an import tool like Jitterbit or Skyvia.